# ELR_EL2 value has be changed in ARMv8 ERET ? Why?

Tags: arm, virtualization

I'm writing a virtualization project in armv8 using VHE.

When I try to switch host hypervisor to guest OS, my switch code as follows:

```
/*
 * void __vcpu_entry(void *regs)
 * x0 = pc, x1 = spsr
 */
.globl __vcpu_entry
__vcpu_entry:
    //RESTORE_CONTEXT
    LDP     X0, X1, [X0]
    MSR     ELR_EL2, X0
    MSR     SPSR_EL2, X1
    ERET
```

In this code, I simplified the other registers' restore process and just stay PC and SPSR value for ERET.

My view is, in first time schedule into vcpu/VM, we change PC to 0x00208000, which is entry for guest OS.

**BUT** the result of experiment is that **the value of ELR_EL2 has be changed to 0x00000200**. And this address is not support and no stage-2 MMU map, it causes Instruction Abort then Panic.

```
[Debug] c->regs.spsr = 0x000003c5
[Debug] c->regs.pc   = 0x00208000
[Info] Create 1 vCPUs success for 0th VM
[Debug] memcpy src: 0x00208000 to dst: 0x11208000
[Info] Load OS img OK
[Info] Run 0th VM first time
msh >[Debug] vcpu_sche_in, 239
[Debug] load_stage2_setting, 228
[Debug] activate_trap, 195
[Debug] __vcpu_entry
[Debug] rt_hw_trap_sync, 109
[Debug] rt_hw_handle_low_sync, 72
[Info]   ESR_EL2 = 0x82000006
[Info]   HCR_EL2 = 0x8008001b
[Info]   FAR_EL2 = 0x00000200
[Info]  VBAR_EL1 = 0x09419800
[Info]  VBAR_EL2 = 0x09419800
[Info] VTTBR_EL2 = 0x09460000
[Info]  SPSR_EL2 = 0x000003c5
[Info]   ELR_EL2 = 0x00000200
[Panic] ec_iabt_low_handler, 50
error exception:
Execption:
X00:0x0000000000000000 X01:0x0000000000000000 X02:0x0000000000000000 X03:0x0000000000000000
X04:0x0000000000000000 X05:0x0000000000000000 X06:0x0000000000000000 X07:0x0000000000000000
X08:0x0000000000000000 X09:0x0000000000000000 X10:0x0000000000000000 X11:0x0000000000000000
X12:0x0000000000000000 X13:0x0000000000000000 X14:0x0000000000000000 X15:0x0000000000000000
X16:0x0000000000000000 X17:0x0000000000000000 X18:0x0000000000000000 X19:0x0000000000000000
X20:0x0000000000000000 X21:0x0000000000000000 X22:0x0000000000000000 X23:0x0000000000000000
X24:0x0000000000000000 X25:0x0000000000000000 X26:0x0000000000000000 X27:0x0000000000000000
X28:0x0000000000000000 X29:0x0000000000000000 X30:0x0000000000000000
SPSR  :0x00000000000003c5
EPC   :0x0000000000000200
Now is at EL2
HCR_EL2 = 0x000000048008001b
ESR_EL2 = 0x0000000082000006
FAR_EL2 = 0x0000000000000200
VBAR_EL1= 0x0000000009419800
VBAR_EL2= 0x0000000009419800
SPSR_EL2= 0x00000000000003c5
ELR_EL2 = 0x0000000000000200
```

So, I want to know How/Why ELR_EL2's value has been changed??? Other projects code write as this too!!

Please all experts give some advice and it's very important to me! THANKS!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMh5S.jpg)

Comment: more description in Chinese at this link : https://club.rt-thread.org/ask/question/dae1511c1579af3e.html

Comment: Please post the error as text not an image.